# Change text in table cell when link in another cell on the same row is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have table that is populated with items from a database. There is a column to "tick" each item, which calls to the database to change the status of that item to "Valid" - that part works. To save me having to refresh the page though, I would like to then update the text on the page after the ajax call so that it reads "Valid" instead of submitted. What is the correct code to achieve this? Where am I going wrong? Without success, I have also attempted to get the tick to go green once clicked.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
      <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Summary</h4>
      <hr />
      <table id="stationCount" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Place</th>
          <th>Submission Date</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Confirm</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p id="lblId" class="form-control-static" contenteditable="false">
              159
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p id="lblPlaceName" class="form-control-static" contenteditable="false">
              Somewhere
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SurveyId field is required." id="Items_0__SurveyId" name="Items[0].SurveyId" value="159" />
            <p id="lblSubmittedOn" class="form-control-static" contenteditable="false" title="27/03/2018 11:04:47">
              27/03/2018
            </p>
          </td>
          <td class="status" id="159">
            <p asp-for="Submitted">
              Submitted
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-default ConfirmLink' style="color: #808080 " data-url='/Controller/ValidateSurvey' data-id="159">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p id="lblId" class="form-control-static" contenteditable="false">
              3
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p id="lblPlaceName" class="form-control-static" contenteditable="false">
              Somewhere else
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SurveyId field is required." id="Items_5__SurveyId" name="Items[5].SurveyId" value="3" />
            <p id="lblSubmittedOn" class="form-control-static" contenteditable="false" title="21/01/2018 00:00:00">
              21/01/2018
            </p>
          </td>
          <td class="status" id="3">
            <p asp-for="Submitted">
              Expired
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-default ConfirmLink' style="color: #808080" data-url='/Controller/ValidateSurvey' data-id="3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                </a>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

$(function() {
 //Document.ready//
 //link up event handler
 $(".ConfirmLink").click(function() {

   // Get the id from the link
   var recordToConfirm = $(this).attr("data-id");
   var postToUrl = $(this).attr("data-url");


   $.ajax(postToUrl, {
     type: "post",
     data: {
       "id": recordToConfirm
     },
     dataType: "json"
   }).done(function(data) {
     // Successful requests get here

   });

   if ($(this).css('color') === '#808080') {
     $(this).css('color', '#008000');
   } else {
     $(this).css('color', '#808080');
   }

   $("#" + recordToConfirm + " td.status").html('Valid');

 });
});
```

I have set up a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/a4zhpt7L/4/

Comment: Are you using knockout or jQuery? If jQuery here's a working fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/a4zhpt7L/12/

Comment: @maxshuty thanks, that is helpful. However I would prefer to put it after the ajax call so I can implement it into the "success" region - it would make sense to only go green on success of the ajax call. My main concern is trying to get the Status column text to update to say "Valid" once the ajax has run. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a4zhpt7L/23/ - see my comments and play around with that fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I added `$(this).closest('tr').children('td.status').children('p').text('Valid');` which works to update the status column :)

Answer (score 0):

To do everything you want, change some things:

- Change `if ($(this).css('color') === '#808080')` to `if ($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(128, 128, 128)')`, because jQuery returns a rgb code instead of a hex code.
- Change  `$("#" + recordToConfirm + " td.status").html('Valid');` to `$("td.status#" + recordToConfirm).html('Valid');`, because the `td.status` was placed incorrectly.

I hope this also fixes your ajax problem.